# google tv HTML5 template video not playing

Tags: google-tv

I have downloaded the HTML5 Template2 for Google TV, I have modified the DataProvider.js file in order to hard-code my videos, video-thumbnails links &  info.

This site works very well on a chrome browser  when running on a computer. 
here is my site
http://mob11.zxq.net/

I made an APK with Phonegap for android and it plays very well for my Nexus7.

However, when I downloaded the same APK to my Visio-Co start google tv buddy box,  the app display perfectly but the videos don't play at all.
Also When I try to go on my site using the chrome browser inside google tv, the site itself display properly, but again the videos don't play.

```
This is a sample of what my dataProvider.js looks like

 var gtv = gtv || {
 jq: {}
 };

  /** * DataProvider class. Defines a provider for all data (Categories, Images & Videos) shown in the template.
  */

gtv.jq.DataProvider = function() { 
};

var x = new gtv.jq.DataProvider();


 gtv.jq.DataProvider.prototype.getData = function() {

  var tourism = [ 
{
sources:
['https://s3.amazonaws.com/besthaitivids/tourism/welcometohaiti.mp4'],
title: 'Welcome to Haiti',
thumb: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/besthaitipic/tourism/touristlogo.jpg',
description: ['Bienvenue en Haiti'],
subtitle: 'La Perle des antilles'
}
];

var data = {
categories: [
{
name: 'Tourisim',
videos: tourism
}
]
};
```

How can I make the videos play on chrome when I access my site inside google tv?

How can I make the videos play in my Google APK APP installed on my Visio-costar google tv?

Any help will be greatly appreciate thanks so much.

Comment: I can get the 'Now playing' video to play by hitting the play button explicitly or pressing spacebar, but they won't play by selecting the thumbnail like in the live example here http://gtv-resources.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/templates/html-02/index.html. Why?